# c++ pointer to function not changed

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have defined some functions  and I print their address like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;

std::string func()
{
    return "hello world\n";

}

int func2(int n)
{
    if (n==0)
    {
        cout << func2 << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << func2 << std::endl;

    return n + func2(n - 1);
}

//================================================
int main()
{
    int (*fun)(int) = func2;

    cout << fun;

    cout << std::endl << func2(3);
}
```

When I print the function's name (address) they all print `1` on my compiler (Mingw gcc 4.8 ).

Is it OK or it should differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not printing the address because it's now converted to a boolean value.

But you can do e.g. this:

```
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long int *>(func2) << std::endl;
```

Now you'll get the actual address.

Comment: Assuming that the size of a function pointer is not larger than the size of `unsigned long long int`. You should also add `const` to the cast to prevent accidents.

Comment: Yeah, well...in C++11 long long is at least 64 bits.

Comment: So? What if pointers are 128-bits in the future? Once they were only 16-bits.

Comment: This may cause an alignment violation, if it even exists .. there's no reason to use any pointer type other than `void *`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. I didn't spot the *

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't exist an overload of `operator<<` for `std::ostream` that takes a function pointer. Thus the `operator<<(std::ostream&, bool)` overload is prefered. The address of a function is always evaluated to `true` when converted to `bool`. Thus, 1 is printed.

Alternatevely, if a function pointer is not larger than the size of a data pointer, you could cast your function pointer to a `void*` via `reinterpret_cast` and evoke the `operator<<(std::ostream&, void*)` overload and thus get the actual address of the function printed.

```
int (*fun)(int) = func2;
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(fun) << std::endl;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87ddab46d7fa26b1)

However, as correctly Neil and M.M mentioned in the comments there's no standard conversion from a function pointer to a data pointer, and this could evoke undefined behaviour.

Alternatively, and in my humble opinion properly, you could format your function pointer as a `char` array buffer and convert its address to a string in the following way:

```
unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&func2);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
for(int i(sizeof(func2) - 1); i >= 0; --i) ss << std::setw(2) 
                                              << static_cast<unsigned int>(p[i]);
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26db51c8be491d39)

Comment: Assuming that the size of a function pointer is not larger than the size of a data pointer. You should also add `const` to the cast to prevent accidents.

Comment: note: this conversion to `void *` is not required to exist

Comment: @M.M I know, mentioned the UB and proposed an alternative safer way.

Comment: @NeilKirk, mentioned the UB and proposed an alternative safer way.